# iOS - navigation controller from storyboard

Tags: ios

I have embedded my view controller in a navigation controller on my storyboard, then added a table view which I configured from code. I'm trying to make it, when I click a row in the table, it should change the view and putting the subview into the stack, however I can't access the navigation controller.

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:disclosureView animated:YES];
```

When this code launches, it gives the error: " NavController[990:c07] Application tried to push a nil view controller on target . "

Comment: This is not an Xcode question.

Comment: Are you sure disclosureView is a UIViewController object?

Comment: Why wouldn't it be an Xcode question, when I'm writing it in Xcode and the problem I'm having is not knowing how Xcode names a navigation controller dropped onto the storyboard :|

Comment: It's a UITableViewController.

Comment: Errors says disclosureView (which should be named disclosureViewController to avoid confusions) is nil. Can you show it's initialization?

Comment: Can you post more code, so we can see how you create your UITableViewController.

Comment: I've simply created a new Objective-C class, UITableViewController subclass, and changed the numberOfSectionsInTableView: to return 1, numberOfRowsInSection to return the number of objects in an array and linked it's delegate and datasource, everything else is left as Xcode generated it.

Comment: Try with **PresentViewController**...?

Comment: What do you mean by that? PresentViewController undeclared.

Comment: [self.navigationController presentViewController:disclosureView animated:YES completion:nil];

Comment: Did that, error:
NavController[2344:c07] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Application tried to present a nil modal view controller on target <UINavigationController: 0x715d2c0>.'

Comment: Ok .. I need to know the way You were doing ..?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/32462/discussion-between-user2212172-and-kumar-kl)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope that you didn't get call the ViewController properly :

```
if(indexPath.row == 0)

   UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:nil];
        UIViewController *disclosureView = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"disclosureView" ];

        [self.navigationController pushViewController:disclosureView animated:YES];
```

Here is the screenShot for getting the UIViewController identifier:
[image]