# error when i am calling next view controller

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, view, uivewcontroller

i am getting an error when i am calling next view controller, i want to call a view controller that a action continue .this screen will come  appear first time only when we run first time.
controller is not going next view.

```
-(void)viewDidLoad
{
    welcomePage *temp = [[welcomePage alloc]initWithNibName:@"welcomePage" bundle:nil];       
    [self presentViewController:temp animated:YES completion:^(void){}];

}
```

Warning: Attempt to present  on  whose view is not in the window hierarchy!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one..

You change the  code in Appdelegate.m didFinishLaunchingWithOptions method like this

```
self.viewController = [[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController" bundle:nil];
UINavigationController *nav=[[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:self.viewController];
self.window.rootViewController = nav;
```

And in your ViewDidLoad method like this..

```
welcomePage *temp = [[welcomePage alloc]initWithNibName:@"welcomePage" bundle:nil];       
[self.navigationController presentViewController:temp animated:YES completion:nil];
```

For dismissing viewcontroller you can write following code in welcomepage button action

```
-(IBAction)dismiss:(id)sender{
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Comment: kalyani puvvada ,it is working ,now how to go  viewcontroler after clicked the button that is in welcome page.

Answer (score 0):

use this code

```
-(void)viewDidLoad
{
    welcomePage *temp = [[welcomePage alloc]initWithNibName:@"welcomePage" bundle:nil];       
    [self presentViewController:temp animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Comment: its showing Warning: Attempt to present <welcomePage: 0x71564d0> i used this

Answer (score 0):

If You are using Storyboard : Use this

> instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier

```
    UIViewController objController  = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"StoryBoard Id"];
 [self presentViewController:objController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

To Set Storybaord ID , [Check Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17338172/ios-navigation-controller-from-storyboard/17339153#17339153) .

Comment: i dont have any storyboard

Answer (score 0):

That error means you are trying to present a modal view controller from a view controller that is not currently in the screen.

Answer (score 0):

This error means that you are trying to present 'welcome page' from a view that is not on the screen yet.

Knowing that simply moving the code to the viewDidAppear method doesn't work for you, what you can try to do is this:

```
-(void)viewDidAppear
{
    [self presentWelcome];
}

- presentWelcome {
welcomePage *temp = [[welcomePage alloc]initWithNibName:@"welcomePage" bundle:nil];       
    [self presentViewController:temp animated:YES completion:^(void){}];
}
```

What happens here is that when the view appears (so when it is in the view hierarchy), the controller starts a function that calls the other viewController. hope this solves your problem.

Hope this helps you!

Comment: i used this code .it is not working .i am calling one viewcontroller to welcomepage controller but its not going in that screen.both are xib not a storyboard

Comment: just to rule this out: try to replace ^(void){} with NULL. and another possibility is that you are using storyboards: if you do, you should change the way you create an instance of your viewcontroller. please tell me if you do and what's the result of my suggested edit.

Comment: Warning: Attempt to present <welcomePage: 0x8069800> on <ViewController: 0x8064e30> whose view is not in the window hierarchy!
welcome page is not coming ,i am using this code inside viewDidLoad method

Comment: I updated my answer because the error you give me confirms that you are loading you viewController to early. please tell me whether it works.